# Table Query from an Access MS DB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to import the records from an Access database for the current month and need the records to be displayed in my `datagridview` on form load not a button click. My reason for this is if a end user opens the program it could take some time to load all the records, so I want to only retrieve the records entered for the current month and obviously year when the form loads. I am new to coding hence the reason I'm asking the people on here with loads of experience.

My code for connection is as follows.

```
Public Sub GetData()

con.Open()

Dim dt As New DataTable("tbLMPH")
Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbLMPH WHERE Year(IDday) = Year(Now()) AND Month(IDday) = Month(Now())", con)                                                                       rs.Fill(dt)

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.Refresh()

Label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count

rs.Dispose()

con.Close()

If Val(Label1.Text) = 1 Then

    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index

    TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
    TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
    TextBox4.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
    TextBox5.Text = DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value
    TextBox6.Text = DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value
    TextBox7.Text = DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value

End If
' Display_Data()

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Me.TbLMPHTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MaindbDataSet.tbLMPH)
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.jimmy2, AudioPlayMode.Background)
Display_Data()
Timer1.Start()
Label2.ForeColor = Color.White
Display_Data()
 End Sub
```

Comment: If you are trying to import records, where's the code to retrieve data ? 

And for a Suggestion, use `Parameterized Queries`

Comment: Public Sub GetData()
     con.Open()
     Dim dt As New DataTable("tbLMPH")
    Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tbLMPH where IDday='" & TextBox1.Text & "' ", con)
    rs.Fill(dt)
     DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
     Label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count
     rs.Dispose()
     con.Close()

Comment: If Val(Label1.Text) = 1 Then
         Dim i As Integer
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
         TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
        TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
        TextBox4.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
        TextBox5.Text = DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value
        TextBox6.Text = DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value
        TextBox7.Text = DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value
     End If
    ' Display_Data()
End Sub

Comment: Sorry I had to split it.

Comment: edit your question and insert into code into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just modifying your code, Use following code :

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim ds as new DataSet
Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tbLMPH where IDday='" & TextBox1.Text & "' ", con)
rs.Fill(dt)
ds.Fill(rs)
dt=ds.Tables(0)

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.Refresh()

TextBox2.Text=dt.rows(0).Item(1)
label1.text = dt.Rows.Count()
```

Use this code to retrieve the data from database. In case of any query, feel free to ask.

Comment: TextBox2.Text=dt.rows(<Row Number>).Item(<Column Name or Column Number>) Do I need to insert my column number and column name into these <> OK, now if I am using this code, how will I query my DB to display the current months records

Comment: Just use your desired `Row Number` and `ColumnNumber` or `ColumnName` instead of `<Row Number>` and `<ColumnNumber>` or `<ColumnName>`

Comment: Do you want to count the number of rows retrieved ? 

use `dt.Rows.Count()` method to do that

Comment: And by the way, do not edit my answer. instead ask here, i'll edit myself

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise I did. My appologies

Comment: Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim ds as new DataSet
Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tbLMPH where IDday='" & TextBox1.Text & "' ", con)
rs.Fill(dt)
ds.Fill(rs)
dt=ds.Tables(0)

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.Refresh()

TextBox2.Text=dt.rows(0).Item(1)
dt.Rows.Count()

Comment: Thats the same code i posted. Just check if it works as you want.

Comment: I I added the column number and the row count for you to check its correct

Comment: Just wondering if this will retrieve my records for the current month                                                                                                        Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim ds as new DataSet
Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbLMPH WHERE Year(IDday) = Year(Now()) AND Month(IDday) = Month(Now())", con)
rs.Fill(dt)
ds.Fill(rs)
dt=ds.Tables(0)

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.Refresh()

TextBox2.Text=dt.rows(0).Item(1)
label1.text = dt.Rows.Count()

Comment: Code will be same. Difference is the query you will be using. You the right query and you'll get what you want. By the way, accept as answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Thanks Mahadev. Worked a treat!

Comment: Accept as answer and close the question